# Azure Function - Queue trigger Function stops processing message in between unexpectedly

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, async-await, azure-functions

In our project have multiple queue function which process message when one complete, all function execute in sequence for one message, but multiple message can be execute in parallel. When doing load test pass 72 request to function, each function need to do some operation on message
 `{ "version": "2.0", "extensions": { "queues": { "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:10", "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:00.100", "batchSize": 6, "maxDequeueCount": 2 }, "functionTimeout": "-1" }  }`
this is host.json of function project. The problem is sometime function does not complete processing of message, function dequeue the message for processing but does not complete it, not able to understand what is issue behind it, below are the images of function settings in azure
[image]
[image]

```
 public class CreateTempVMTempTablesFunction
{
    private static Container container;
    private static IProcessingFunctionService _processingFunctionService; 
    private static IAzureFunctionFailuresRepository _azureFunctionFailuresRepository;
    private static ITrackLogEventsService _trackLogEventsService;

    [FunctionName("CreateTempVMTempTablesFunction")]
    public static async Task Run([QueueTrigger("%environment-plan%" + AzureFunctionConstants.CreateTempTableQueue, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
    {
        string ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
        var start = DateTime.Now;
        FunctionStatusEnum IsSuccess = FunctionStatusEnum.Success;
        log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem} - {start}");

        Guid tempid = new Guid(myQueueItem);
        TempVM tempVM = new TempVM();
        try
        {
            container = BusinessLogic.Helpers.SimpleInjectorWebApiInitializer.InitializeSingleton();;
           
            _processingFunctionService = container.GetInstance<IProcessingFunctionService>();
            _azureFunctionFailuresRepository = container.GetInstance<IAzureFunctionFailuresRepository>();
            _trackLogEventsService = container.GetInstance<ITrackLogEventsService>();

            tempVM = await _processingFunctionService.GetById(tempid);
            if (tempVM != null)
            {
                FunctionStatusEnum IsAlreadyPerformed = await _azureFunctionFailuresRepository.GetAzureFunctionFailureStatus(AzureFunctionConstants.CreateTempVMTempTablesFunction, tempVM.Id);

                if (IsAlreadyPerformed != FunctionStatusEnum.Success)
                {
                        ResponseData response = await _processingFunctionService.CreateTempVMTempTables(tempid);
                }
                else
                {
                    ErrorMessage = AzureFunctionConstants.FunctionAlreadyProcessed;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorMessage = AzureFunctionConstants.TempVMNotFound;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            IsSuccess = FunctionStatusEnum.Failed;
            ErrorMessage = ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            AzureFunctionFailures azureFunctionFailures = new AzureFunctionFailures()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                FunctionName = AzureFunctionConstants.CreateTempVMTempTablesFunction,
                QueueItem = myQueueItem,
                ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage,
                StartTime = start,
                EndTime = DateTime.Now,
                FailureTypeId = tempid,
                FunctionStatus = IsSuccess,
                ProcessTime = (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds,
            };
            await _azureFunctionFailuresRepository.Add(azureFunctionFailures);
        }
        log.LogInformation($"End Time : {DateTime.Now} - QueueItem {myQueueItem}");
        log.LogInformation($"Total Time : {DateTime.Now - start} - QueueItem {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors in the logs that might give some indication? If you could provide a minimal code example for reproducing the error would also help greatly in trying to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry, but their is no log for this, and this is happen when we have add 72 messages at one time, but this is happen randomly, and there are multiple functions in project,

Comment: So the failed processes don't even make it to `log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem} - {start}");`? Even that bit of information is helpful to know since it means that the message is probably failing within the Functions host and you are more likely to find related failure into in Kudu than App Insights.

Comment: Sometimes the log added in app insights, but only 1st log

Comment: So you are getting say 70 out of 72 startTime messages and only 65 endTime? (aka the point of failure is inconsistent). I'm guessing you've already checked your database for error messages, but have you looked at the host logging in the Kudu console to make sure there is nothing there? One other thing that could be causing issues is that because you catch the error but don't rethrow it from the catch block the host process doesn't know it needs to retry that message instead of completing it. Rethrowing also means that the error should make it to App Insights even if your custom logging fails.

Comment: Not able to understand anything in kudu, and there is no error in log, not able to understand what is the issue

Comment: There may not be anything helpful there, it's just something to check. If there is it will be under LogFiles -> Application -> Functions. This one will probably be easier to work though via 1:1 support since it is so difficult to track down. If you don't have a support contract, you can send me an email to azcommunity(at)microsoft.com with a link to this thread and I will enable your account for a one-time free ticket.

Comment: I have check logfiles in kudu, but there date and time doesn't give me clear idea which logfile I can check, I have added one screenshot of log files in question. the date time specified in  modified is it in India time zone or in other time zone

Comment: Pretty much everything in Azure is stored in UTC by default, and the logfile names will follow that rule. Some of the information in the portal is converted for you when it is displayed, but raw logs will still have the UTC timestamps. If you remember when the issue occurred you can look at logs around that time, or you could recreate it to get more recent logs. FYI the offer to help set you up with support still stands.